# javafx: bind a Label's textFillProperty to a value

Tags: javafx, binding

I have a class `currentVoyage` which has a SimpleFloatProperty `profitLossProperty()` which is bound to a label such:

```
 profitLossLabel.textProperty().bind(
Bindings.format("$%.0f", currentVoyage.profitLossProperty()
));
```

This works fine, so the label updates when the profitLoss value changes. 
Now I want the text in the label to turn red when the value is below zero. I've tried the code below, but the compiler complains the `then()` method doesn't recognise the Color object (but it seems the `otherwise()` method does). I'm sure its something simple, but can't figure out what...

Here's the code:

```
profitLossLabel.textFillProperty().bind(
 Bindings.when(currentVoyage.profitLossProperty().greaterThanOrEqualTo(0)
.then(Color.BLACK).otherwise(Color.RED)
));
```

Comment: Is this the exact code you use? If it is, you need to move one of the last `)`s to the end of the second line (just before `.then(`), since `then` should be called for the object returned by `Bindings.when` not for the `BooleanBinding` returned by `currentVoyage.profitLossProperty().greaterThanOrEqualTo(0)`. BTW: for readability I'd prefer to move one of the `))` in the first code snippet to the previous line, since it belongs to the `format` method, not to the `bind` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; when I do that the compiler complains: incompatible types: ObjectBinding<Color> cannot be converted to ObservableValue<? extends Paint> 
Do I need to cast something?

Comment: OK figured it out-- you were correct fabian-- I just needed to
`import javafx.scene.paint.Color;`
instead of:
`import java.awt.Color;`